# Aldrich's Inconsistent Physical Appearance? (possible spoilers)

Tags: dark-souls-3

I've seen images of Aldrich on the internet, and he appears to be a relatively normal looking human, despite some malformations.

But in the opening sequence, he is just a mass of black sludge that flows out of a coffin. This mass also seems to contain bones like the Gel enemies from Bloodborne, but I am not sure.

Is there a reason for this?

**Edit**
Someone in Firelink told me that Aldrich (though I can't remember the phrasing) ate so many people that he bloated, but then turned soft like... some material that I cannot remember the word for. That being said,  how does eating people cause you to puff up and melt into a moving mass of self aware cannibalistic tar?

Comment: I found the phrasing: "He ate so many that he bloated like a drowned pig, then softened into sludge..."

Answer (score 4):

The prevailing theory is that yes, Aldrich is the ooze, and the human portion is Gwyndolin from Dark Souls 1, in the process of being devoured. The Darkmoon Longbow's lore, *"Longbow of Darkmoon Gwyndolin, who was gradually devoured by Aldrich"* gives weight to this. Additionally, when you lock onto the boss, you focus a large mass inside the ooze tail rather than the human part, and after defeating it and placing the Cinders back at Firelink, you place some piece that is much larger than Gwyndolin's skull (and likely the true skull of Aldrich).

Comment: Is Gywndolin alive, or is Aldrich doing a more advanced version of "swinging his corpse around?" Also, if the sludge on the floor is Aldrich as well, then why has he not devoured the player?

Comment: Player isn't tasty enough?  Honestly, don't give FROM software ideas for the next boss.  I don't want to fight a version of him where the entire floor damages me.